# PHP - json encode/decode process convert associative array to object

Tags: php, json, serialization, associative-array

i need to store php variables into files so i decide to serialize or jsonize (maybe jsonify XD) them. 
For portability purpose i prefer json solution...
During test i notice associative array are json-decoded as object and i cant use it as associative array but i have to use as object.
Non-associative array are json-decoded correctly as non-associative array..
am i doing something wrong?
or just this is a normal behavior of php json functions

here the example code

```
$test = array("test1" => 1, "test2" => 2);

$json = json_decode(json_encode($test));

$serialize = unserialize(serialize($test));

//output -> stdClass::__set_state(array( 'test1' => 1, 'test2' => 2, ))
// cant access  to $json["test1"] as in $test but $json->test why?????
var_export($json);

//ouptut -> array ( 'test1' => 1, 'test2' => 2, )
//here i can $serialize["test1"] 
var_export($serialize);
```

Comment: Just use `json_decode(json_encode($test), true);`, you'll get an array instead of an object.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `json_decode($test, true)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can give set a second Parameter. When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```

output:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}

array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```

Comment: and what about nested?

Answer (score 0):

yes i already use it...
if i use `json_decode($test, true)` works on associative array but wont work for object cause original object will be decoded as array...
So the problem is i must have the decoded variables as the original variables (for both case). 
I encode my variables then store in a file then decode and i must access them in the same way i access the original, so if the original was associative array i must access it as associative array `x["field"]`, if the original variables was a object i have to access as object `x->field`.
Serialize do the job, json no, thats my concern... maybe json is not thought for that purpose?